# Two elements that generate a group of order $22$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> A group $G$ of order $22$ contains elements $x$ and $y$, where $x \neq 1$ and $y$ is not a power of $x$.  Show that the subgroup generated by these two elements is the whole group.

I'm not allowed to use Sylow's theorems, only Lagrange.

Attempt:  I can see that the order of $x$ must be either 2 or 11 (if it were 22 then $y$ would be a power of $x$ as $G=<x>$).  --I feel that the order of $y$ also cannot be 22 but cannot prove it--.  If the order of $x$ is 11 AND the order of $y$ is 11, then $|G|=21$ because $<x>\cap<y>=\varnothing$, a contradiction. This is where I am lost, because I don't see why the order of $x$ and $y$ cannot both be $2$.  After this case, though, then I think I am done because the orders of $x$ and $y$ have to be either 11 and 2 or 2 and 11 (say the order of $x$ is 11).  Then the set
$$ \{ e, x, x^2, \dotsc, x^{10}, y, yx, \dotsc, yx^{10} \} = G. $$

Comment: The order of $y$ can be $22$. But then $G = \langle y\rangle = \langle x,y\rangle$, so all's well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $H = \langle x,y\rangle$ the subgroup generated by $x$ and $y$. Since $x \neq 1$, it cannot be trivial, so it can have order $2,\, 11$ or $22$. If it had order $2$, then either $y = x$ or $y = 1$, so $y$ is a power of $x$, contradicting the premise. If the order were $11$, then $x$ is a generator of the cyclic group of prime order, hence $y$ is a power of $x$, contradicting the premise. So the only possibility that remains is $[H : 1] = 22$.

Comment: Are you saying that if $|H|=11$, then $<x>=H$?  Is this because $x \neq 1$?

Comment: Yes. If $\lvert H\rvert = 11$, then $H$ is a group of prime order. All groups of prime order are cyclic, and all elements except $1$ generate the group.